# Como eu faço para adicionar mais elementos a um array no php

Tags: php, array

Estou criando uma função pra validar dados de formulário, e queria saber como eu adiciono os erros ao `array`, a cada erro novo ele add no array???

```
<?php
// Função criada para validar todo tipo de formularios em uma unica função \\



function valida_formularios($nome){

    // Criamos um array de erro
    $erro = array();

    //Verificamos se exite uma variavel nome setada
    if(!isset($nome)){
        // Caso não exite o programa continua normal
    }else{
        if(empty($nome)){
            $erro = 'Variavel nome está fazia';
        }else{

            // Rodamos a validação de nome
            $nome = str_replace(" ","",$nome); // Retira os espaços caso aja

            // Verifica se a números no nome
            if(filter_var($nome, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) === '' ? false : true){
                $erro = 'É proibido usar numeros no seu nome';
            }




             // Conta o numero de caracteres
            $cont_nome = strlen($nome);


            // Verifica se a variavel tem menos de 3 letras
            if($cont_nome <= 3){
                $erro = 'A variavel deve conter no minimo 3 letras';
            }

            // Verifica se a variavel tem mais que 16 letrar
            if($cont_nome >= 16){
                $erro = 'seu nome não pode ter mais que 16 caracters';
            }

            return $erro;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No php é possível adicionar elementos a um `array` de diversas formas, elas são:

**Dado seu array `$erro`:**

- Adicionando elemento em uma posição específica do array:

  `$erro[5] = $elemento;`
- Adicionando elemento na última posição do array com função:

  `array_push($erro, $elemento);`
- Adicionando elemento na última posição do array:

  `$erro[] = $elemento;`

Answer (score 3):

Para adicionar itens em um array você deve utilizar a função array_push.
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-push.php

Por exemplo:

```
$erro = [];
array_push($erro, "Erro 1");
array_push($erro, "Erro 2");
print_r($erro);
```

Comment: ah entendi, eu tava tentando usar '.' para tentar concatenar, vlw.

Comment: Não se esqueça de marcar como resposta se te ajudou ;)